# Shadow not visible on texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows

In cycles I have imported an image as a plane.
I've added an object to it and the default lamp. I see shadow from my own object onto the object itself but my object does not have any shadow on the plane/image/texture.

If I select the object and the plane the Cycles settings have for Ray Visibility everything turned on.

Comment: could it be just too light to see it? can you show your setup (scene, light, nodes)? ON a simple test setup (cube, image imported as plane, standard lamp, it works...)

Comment: Found the problem! My image as a texture was imported with emission (material -> surface -> emission) but I have changed it back to (material -> surface -> Diffuse BSDF) and it works now ;-) 
thanks!

Comment: Your comment about Diffuse BSFD just solved my issue with shadows on the texture that I was fighting for 2 days