# Skybox is not visible after rendering

Tags: rendering, camera, skybox

Trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSii7P0j420) tutorial and create a skybox but in Blender 2.93

Can't find some buttons from the video, e.g. make material shadeless, maybe this is why can't see the skybox on the rendered image.

**Question**

How to render the skybox?

[image: Blender]

**Update**

I was able to render the skybox by going to `Material Properties` of the container (cube) and setting the `Surface` property to `Emission`. Unfortunately, as was mentioned in the comments, it emits light that makes all other objects inside the container shadeless which is still not what I expected...

[image: Render with emission]

Comment: This tutorial is deprecated since it relies on Blender Internal render engine which was discontinued in the 2.8+ versions. You can however do the same things using Eevee or Cycles, it should work out of the box. To make a material shadeless, you can use an Emission Shader instead of the Principled BSDF node and set the strength to 1. Note that it will emit light, which might not be what you want

Comment: In Cycles you can also plug the image directly into the material output without the need of plugging an Emission shader inbetween. By default the image texture then works as if it was an Emission shader set to a strength of 1 and it's shadeless since no "shader" is involved.

Comment: @Gorgious Thanks. I found this option and unfortunately it emits too much light. Would be nice if all objects inside the container could still have an alternative source of light and shadows.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Thanks. I tried to exclude `Emission` from the chain of nodes in the `Shader Editor`, but the result is the same, the image itself still emits too much light, making all objects inside the skybox shadeless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it work. Mistakes that I made on the way.

1. As Gordon Brinkman mentioned in the comments Cycles engine renders HDRI texture out of the box. Meanwhile, any scene sets Eevee engine as the default one. After switching to Cycles I was able to see my HDRI texture.
2. As it was mentioned by Gorgious, even setting the engine to Cycles the light seemed too bright so all objects inside the SkyBox looked like they were floating in the air without shadows. Unfortunately, the solution with MixShader didn't solve this issue, but I found a couple of tutorials that brought me closer to what I wanted. One mentions adding Diffuse BSDF before Material Output in the nodes editor. The second one suggests checking Shadow Catcher in the material properties of the ground plane.

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBCZBsV-GbA
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsAUfQlZH_w

3. After watching 2 tutorials above I was able to see the shadow on the ground plane, but when I tried to add texture to this plane, it broke again.

- with Shadow Catcher enabled entire plane was dark and shadowless
- without Shadow Catcher the plane had normal texture, but still shadowless

After reading comments in [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80934/shadow-not-visible-on-texture) question, I realized that instead of adding Diffuse BSDF to the SkyBox, I would rather add it to the ground plane and ... it worked. Now I have all working together - HDRI sphere, lights, shadows, textures.

[image]

**Material settings of the HDRI sphere**

[image]

**Material settings of the ground plane**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Cycles, this setup (Is Camera Ray output from the Light Path node plugged into the factor of a Mix Shader) applied to the skybox cube will make the material appear shadeless while not illuminating the scene.

[image]